# Testing scollIntoView in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I test scrollIntoView() property in puppeteer?
This is what I tried:

```
  it("should scroll to the right comment", async function() {
    await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:3000/page/test#1',
      { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.waitForSelector("ul.timeline-comments", { visible: true });
    await page.waitForSelector("li.timeline-comment[name='1']", { visible: true });
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector("li.timeline-comment[name='1']").scrollIntoView();
    });
    console.log(result);
  }).timeout(0);

----
This is the result from the console.log(result):
---
undefined
    ✓ should scroll to the right comment (189ms)
```

and here is the part of the code I want to test:

```
$("li.timeline-comment[name='" + comment_id + "']")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Is your question is how you can test if the DOM Element is in the view ? If yes you have to get the coordiantes of the DOM and check if it is present in the view.https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try this